# Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space. Then $\left \|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right \|^2 \le n \sum_{k=1}^n \|a_k\|^2$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Could you verify if my proof for this inequality is fine?

> Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $\| \cdot \|$ its induced norm. Prove that $$\left \|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right \|^2 \le n \sum_{k=1}^n \|a_k\|^2.$$

**Proof:** It follows from $\|a-b\|^2 \ge 0$ that $\langle a, b\rangle \le \frac{\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2}{2}$. Then
\begin{align}
\left \|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right \|^2 &= \left \langle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k, \sum_{h=1}^n a_h \right \rangle \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{h=1}^n \left \langle  a_k,  a_h \right \rangle \\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{h=1}^n \frac{\|a_k\|^2+\|a_h\|^2}{2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n+1)+(n-1)}{2} \|a_k\|^2 = n \sum_{k=1}^n \|a_k\|^2.
\end{align}

This completes the proof.

Comment: Where did you get $n+1$ and $n-1$ from ? I get $\frac { n+n} 2\sum\|a_k\|^{2}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Take $k=1$ as an example. For $(a_1, a_h)$ with $h=1,\ldots,n$, $a_1$ appears $(n+1)$ times. For $(a_h, a_1)$ with $h \neq 1$, $a_1$ appears $(n-1)$ times.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{h=1}^{n}c_k=n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}c_k$. I think you are over-thinking.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're right!!

Comment: If your Hilbert space is over the complex numbers, then the statement $\langle a, b \rangle \le \dots$ is meaningless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is on the right track, but there is a caveat. If the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$, then the inequality
$$\langle a,b\rangle \le \frac{\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2}{2}$$
needs to be replaced by
$$\Re\langle a,b\rangle \le \frac{\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2}{2}.$$

You can still save the proof as follows:

\begin{align}
\left \|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right \|^2 &= \left \langle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k, \sum_{h=1}^n a_h \right \rangle \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{h=1}^n \left \langle  a_k,  a_h \right \rangle \\
&=\Re\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{h=1}^n \left \langle  a_k,  a_h \right \rangle \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{h=1}^n \Re\left \langle  a_k,  a_h \right \rangle \\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{h=1}^n \frac{\|a_k\|^2+\|a_h\|^2}{2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n+1)+(n-1)}{2} \|a_k\|^2 = n \sum_{k=1}^n \|a_k\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Akira You are welcome!

Comment: Your answer assures me that even trivial question may have great answer. So don't be afraid to ask :)